# Check if an item equals to one out of many elements in Python

Tags: python

I want to check if an item from a list equals to any one element out of a given set of n elements, if yes, do some thing.

For example, the most intuitive but of course cumbersome and ugly way is:

```
for item in List:
    if (item == element1) or (item == element2) or ... or (item == elementn):
        do something
```

What are the better ways to check?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use the `in` operator:

```
elements = set((element1, element2, ..., elementn))
...
if item in elements:
   do something
```

Use either a set or a tuple for the elements: a set is faster for lookups but requires the elements be hashable. A tuple is lighter weight for a few elements but gets slower if there are more than a few elements.

Also, unless the elements vary through your loop you should initialise the collection outside the loop to avoid the overhead of creating the set/tuple every time.

Answer (score 4):

```
for item in my_ist:
    if item in (element1, element2, ..., elementn):
        # do something
```

If the order and frequency of the items in `my_list` does not matter, you can also use

```
for item in set(my_list) & set((element1, element2, ..., elementn)):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `if item in list2: do something` with list2 properly initialized with the elements you want to match..