# Is there a shorter way of using multiple 'or's in an assert statement?

Tags: python, assert

```
class weapon:
    def __init__(self, name: str, weapontype : str, range : str, material : str, price : float, quantity : int):

        assert weapontype == "bladed" or weapontype == "blunt" or weapontype == "polearm" or weapontype == "Ranged", f"{weapontype} is not a valid weapontype"
        assert range == "close range" or range == "medium range" or range == "long range", f"{range} is not a valid range"
        assert material == "metal" or material == "wood", f"{material} is not a valid material type"
        
        self.name = name
        self.weapontype = weapontype
        self.range = range
        self.material = material
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
```

Any way i can eliminate the ors? I've looked online and I can't find anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if an item equals to one out of many elements in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997749/check-if-an-item-equals-to-one-out-of-many-elements-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Use `in`:

```
assert weapontype in ["bladed", "blunt", ...]
```

Keep in mind that assertions can be disabled at runtime, so aren't an appropriate way to perform runtime type checking. Raise an explicit `ValueError` instead.

```
if weapontype not in ["bladed", ...]:
    raise ValueError(f'{weapontype} is not a valid weapon type')
```

Comment: it should be `{"bladed", "blunt", ...}` instead because it's more efficient.